# Should acceptance letters be answered?

Tags: publications, etiquette, communication

If somebody receives an email from a journal stating that their paper is accepted for publication, should they write back?  If so, what should they say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be exceptions of which I'm not aware of, but usually, no, you don't reply, unless there are specific queries from the editor.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, together with an acceptance letter, there are instructions of what you should do next.  Like: make any final edits, sign these copyright forms, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the nature of the email you receive.

Needless to say, if you are asked a question in the email, you will want to reply. Moreover, if you have any questions related to how things will continue past acceptance, this can be a good occasion to raise them.

Yet, given your question, I assume neither is the case and we are in a situation where you are asked no questions and everything is clear to you.

- If the email is auto-generated by an editorial management tool and/or pure boilerplate text there is no need to reply and I would advise against doing so.
- If the email is a personal email written to you by a (scientific) editor I recommend to reply. Just thank the editor for the information and express some appreciation. If the process was quick, you could mention this. If the report was detailed, say something positive related to this. If there was a lot of back-and-forth and the editor was helpful and patient, thank for this. If there is nothing specific or you are unsure, just go with "thank you for the good news" as suggested in another answer.

There are some gray-areas, such as email written by technical staff. In doubt, I'd go with a brief reply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reply them back, and most probably it will be bothersome to read every email receives from the author which is not relevant to the progress of your paper. But, if they ask questions etc, then you need to reply.

Comment: See [what are we generally looking for in answers](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/what-are-we-generally-looking-for-in-answers). Generally, answers should contribute something new; if there is an existing answer that is essentially the same as what you want to say, you should vote it up rather than posting another answer that says the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

The courteous thing to do is to write back and say "Thank you for the good news! -- Best, Anonymous Physicist"

There is no need to write back, but being nice is never a bad idea.